# what happens when we delete AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Recently I deleted my AWS account because I was getting unexpected bills. but now I have a doubt that when we delete AWS account does it delete all the running services or Not. If it doesn't then please give me a solution.

Comment: You should contact the official support for this kind of question

Comment: What makes you think this? Why would AWS keep services running for free? Sounds like a backward question because most people would think the opposite. Can you share a source which may have shade some doubts in your mind?

Answer (score 2):

It could be that there is some lag between when you delete and when you receive the bill.  For example, if your billing cycle ends at the end of the month, but you delete your account on the 15th, then you still could get a partial, pro-rated bill, at the end of that month covering the first 15 days.

If the above does not explain it, what I have seen in the past is that some services were not in fact deleted, and were still billing me in the background.  Check your AWS again to verify that it has been deleted, or if not, make sure that there are no active services still billing you.

Comment: how can I check weather the service is still running because after deleting account I can access only billing page ?

Comment: If your account is not even accessible, then you might want to email customer service directly.

Comment: thanks man for helping, I was frightened when I saw the bill.